# Javascript - html image slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some trouble getting my image slideshow to run automatically. I have tried several options but none has worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="showcase">
      <img id="imgs" src="./assets/img/achievement-agreement-arms-1068523.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/main-slideshow.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
let slideImg=['./assets/img/achievement-agreement-arms-1068523.jpg',
'./assets/img/application-calculator-coffee-cup-1050304.jpg',
'./assets/img/chain-close-up-display-1036857.jpg',
'./assets/img/coffee-computer-cup-234394.jpg'];
let i = 0
setTimeout( function slider (){document.imgs.src = slideImg[i]; if (i<slideImg.lenght - 1) {i++;}else{i=0;}, 1000);
window.onload=slideImg;
```

I tried placing a complete path in the array list for the images, but it doesn't work.

Comment: There are typos, missing closing tags and such all over your script. Please validate your code in sites like **jshint** and copy the validated code here if it still doesn't work.

Comment: ok, thank you. i will try that.

Comment: this is what it gave me:                                                                      var slideImg = ['./assets/img/achievement-agreement-arms-1068523.jpg',
'./assets/img/application-calculator-coffee-cup-1050304.jpg',
'./assets/img/chain-close-up-display-1036857.jpg',
 './assets/img/coffee-computer-cup-234394.jpg'];
var i = 0;
setTimeout( function slider () {document.imgs.src = slideImg[i]; if (i < slideImg.lenght - 1) {
i++;
} }, 1000);
window.onload=slideImg;

Comment: don't post code as comment, if you need to show code always edit your question to add it.

Comment: my apologies Calvin, am not too acquainted with how everything works on here. Next time I'll know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the typos and invalid codes, there's some points to be evaluated:

1. `document.imgs` is not going to select a DOM element with `id='imgs'`, you need `document.querySelector('#IdOfElement');` or `document.getElementById('IdOfElement');`
2. `setTimeout()` will only happen once, after that, it won't happen again, in this case the method you are looking for is probable `setInterval()` (it's not a good method to be used, but it works in this case, so go on).
3. I suggest you to make some free online course of basic javascript and also try to pay attention to the code, avoidin those typos you had.

The code below s probably what you need, please take a look.

```js
let slideImg=['./assets/img/achievement-agreement-arms-1068523.jpg',
'./assets/img/application-calculator-coffee-cup-1050304.jpg',
'./assets/img/chain-close-up-display-1036857.jpg',
'./assets/img/coffee-computer-cup-234394.jpg'];
let i = 0
setInterval( function slider (){
  document.querySelector('#imgs').src = slideImg[i]; 
  console.log('new src: '+ slideImg[i]);
  if (i < slideImg.length - 1) {
    i++;
  }else{
    i=0;
  }
  }, 
1000);
window.onload=slideImg;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="showcase">
    <img id="imgs" src="./assets/img/achievement-agreement-arms-1068523.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Calvin for your patience in reading my code and giving your advice. I appreciate it.

Comment: you're welcome, we re here to help if the asker helps himself too.
If this answered your question, I suggest you to mark this as accepted answer to incentivate the S.O community to keep answering your questions

Comment: i'm going to try it now to see if it works. Sometimes, looking at something too long makes one overlook even the obvious. In fact, I feel quite a bit dumb that I hadn't noticed he errors.